# index table by name in R

Tags: r, indexing

I'm having trouble with the dataset .
the data looks like this:

```
>data
      name L1
1   TSS200  1
2   TSS200  1
3   TSS200  1
4   TSS200  1
5   TSS200  2
6   TSS200  3
7  TSS1500  4
8  TSS1500  4
9  TSS1500  4
10  TSS200  4
11  TSS200  5
12   5'UTR  6
13  TSS200  6
```

And I want to index the value based on the L1 , in a increasing manner. For example, for L1=1, there are 4 rows, so the index is 1 to 4; then for L1=2, there is only one row, so the index is 1; L2=3, only one row, index is 1; and so on. output a table like this:

```
      name L1 Index
1   TSS200  1 1
2   TSS200  1 2
3   TSS200  1 3
4   TSS200  1 4
5   TSS200  2 1
6   TSS200  3 1
7  TSS1500  4 1
8  TSS1500  4 2
9  TSS1500  4 3
10  TSS200  4 4
11  TSS200  5 1
12   5'UTR  6 1
13  TSS200  6 2
```

I hope I have stated the question clearly. And thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you clarify what is determining the value of the index? I don't understand the underlying principle.

Comment: @SprengMeister I made some change to my post. Thanks!

Comment: thank you, much clearer now

Comment: The most classic approach for these is `?ave`: `ave(DF$L1, DF$L1, FUN = seq_along)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work if L1 is always increasing.  The answer assumes you have a data frame called `d`

```
data.frame(d, Index = unlist(mapply(seq, 1, rle(d$L1)$lengths)))

      name L1 Index
1   TSS200  1     1
2   TSS200  1     2
3   TSS200  1     3
4   TSS200  1     4
5   TSS200  2     1
6   TSS200  3     1
7  TSS1500  4     1
8  TSS1500  4     2
9  TSS1500  4     3
10  TSS200  4     4
11  TSS200  5     1
12   5'UTR  6     1
13  TSS200  6     2
```

Comment: mapply is too next level for me. will never understand that function

Comment: @Vlo Here I am calling `seq` multiple times and I want to supply 1 as the `from` argument each time and supply each of the values from `rle(d$L1)$lengths` as the `to` argument in turn.  It's basically the same idea as `sapply(rle(d$L1)$lengths, function(x) seq(1, x))`

Comment: That is a good explanation. Is there a reason why FUN is the first argument as opposed most of the other *apply family functions in base R.

Comment: Think of `mapply` as similar in function to `do.call` and it makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  group_by(L1) %>%
  mutate(Index = row_number())

#Source: local data frame [13 x 3]
#Groups: L1
#
#      name L1 Index
#1   TSS200  1     1
#2   TSS200  1     2
#3   TSS200  1     3
#4   TSS200  1     4
#5   TSS200  2     1
#6   TSS200  3     1
#7  TSS1500  4     1
#8  TSS1500  4     2
#9  TSS1500  4     3
#10  TSS200  4     4
#11  TSS200  5     1
#12   5'UTR  6     1
#13  TSS200  6     2
```

Answer (score 3):

`ave` applies a function within groups and returns an equal length vector, so `seq_along` is what you want:

```
  dat$Index <- ave( dat$L1 , dat$L1, FUN=seq_along)

> dat
      name L1 Index
1   TSS200  1     1
2   TSS200  1     2
3   TSS200  1     3
4   TSS200  1     4
5   TSS200  2     1
6   TSS200  3     1
7  TSS1500  4     1
8  TSS1500  4     2
9  TSS1500  4     3
10  TSS200  4     4
11  TSS200  5     1
12   5'UTR  6     1
13  TSS200  6     2
```

Answer (score 3):

And `data.table` approach (of course!)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, Index := seq_len(.N), by = L1]

       name L1 Index
 1:  TSS200  1     1
 2:  TSS200  1     2
 3:  TSS200  1     3
 4:  TSS200  1     4
 5:  TSS200  2     1
 6:  TSS200  3     1
 7: TSS1500  4     1
 8: TSS1500  4     2
 9: TSS1500  4     3
10:  TSS200  4     4
11:  TSS200  5     1
12:   5'UTR  6     1
13:  TSS200  6     2
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a handy `sequence` function.

```
> data$Index <- sequence(rle(data$L1)$lengths)
```

or

```
> data$Index <- sequence(table(data[-1]))
```

both produce

```
> data
      name L1 Index
1   TSS200  1     1
2   TSS200  1     2
3   TSS200  1     3
4   TSS200  1     4
5   TSS200  2     1
6   TSS200  3     1
7  TSS1500  4     1
8  TSS1500  4     2
9  TSS1500  4     3
10  TSS200  4     4
11  TSS200  5     1
12   5'UTR  6     1
13  TSS200  6     2
```